# Платформа для моделирования задач с физики

Tags: физика, моделирование

Нужно смоделировать задачу, где будут физические константы по типу ускорения падания(к примеру можно менять чтобы было не только земное) можно было описать силы действующие на тело в таких случаях(равно ускоренное движение или равномерное). Знаю о geogebra и вопрос состоит в том, если кто пробовал делать такое, то где лучше всего и какой метод реализации?

Comment: `PhysX` какое-нибудь, наверное. Да и другие есть. Я бы взял вообще `Unity 3D` - там сразу и физический движок и отрисовка. Для питона есть `Pymunk`, он 2D вроде.

Comment: Большое спасибо за упоминание unity и physx, как то сам забыл о их существовании. Думаю это и есть ответ на мой вопрос. Ещё раз спасибо!